# Concatenating using index with a dataframe

Tags: r, indexing

I have a table as follows:

```
tableA <-structure(c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L), dim = c(3L, 
3L), dimnames = structure(list(c("0.3", "0.4", 
"0.6"), c("A", "B", "C")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")

 #     A B C
 # 0.3 0 0 3
 # 0.4 1 3 2
 # 0.6 2 0 0

i1 <- structure(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE), dim = c(3L, 3L), dimnames = structure(list(c("0.3", "0.4", 
"0.6"), c("A", "B", "C")), names = c("", "")))

#           A     B     C
#   0.3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#   0.4  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#   0.6 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I would like, for each cell where `i1` is `TRUE`, to add `"(replaced)"`, to the value in `tableA`. I started with converting the table to string values.

```
tableA[] <- lapply(tableA, as.character)
```

And then doing the following:

```
tableA[i1] <- paste0(tableA[i1], " (replaced)")
```

But this returns a list. How should I keep the table format in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` returns a list destroying the data frame. It is not nessesary:

```r
tableA <- structure(c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L), dim = c(
  3L,
  3L
), dimnames = structure(list(c(
  "0.3", "0.4",
  "0.6"
), c("A", "B", "C")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")

i1 <- structure(c(
  FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
  FALSE
), dim = c(3L, 3L), dimnames = structure(list(c(
  "0.3", "0.4",
  "0.6"
), c("A", "B", "C")), names = c("", "")))

tableA[i1] <- paste0(tableA[i1], " (replaced)")
tableA
#>      
#>       A            B C           
#>   0.3 0            0 3           
#>   0.4 1 (replaced) 3 2 (replaced)
#>   0.6 2            0 0
```